# Hide/Disable submit button from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms, uiviewcontroller

How can I hide a webform button from controller action? or Do I do it in webform itself?

There is a condition to hide/disable the button:

```
if (StudentType != "Senior")
{
Hide Button
}
Display Button
```

View:

```
<form method="post" action="/Student/Dispatch/"> 
    <label for="id">Student Number: </label> 
    <input type="text" name="id" value="" /> <br /><br /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Get Student(xls)" name="xls" /> &nbsp;&nbsp 
    <input type="submit" value="Get Student(pdf)" name="pdf" /> 
</form>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult Dispatch(string pdf, string id) { 
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pdf)) { 
        // GetPdf submit button was clicked 
        return StudentPdf(id); 
    } 
    // GetXls submit button was clicked 
    return StudentExcel(id); 
}
```

Comment: Are you using WebForms or MVC? They are two different frameworks with different ways to do what you're asking.

Comment: I have a form which posts to a controller on submit. The two buttons are in the form which I want to hide/display based on StudentType

Comment: Can you post the code for your view and controller method?

Comment: View:
`<form method="post" action="/Student/Dispatch/">
    <label for="id">Student Number: </label>
    <input type="text" name="id" value="" />
    <br /><br />

    <input type="submit" value="Get Student(xls)" name="xls" />  
    &nbsp;&nbsp
    <input type="submit" value="Get Student(pdf)" name="pdf" /> 
</form>`

Controller:
`[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Dispatch(string pdf, string id)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pdf))
    {
        // GetPdf submit button was clicked
        return StudentPdf(id);
    } 

    // GetXls submit button was clicked
    return StudentExcel(id);
}`

Comment: You should edit your answer the next time more code is requested instead of pasting it into a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ViewData dictionary .

Controller:

```
if (StudentType != "Senior")
{
ViewData["isHideButton"] =true;
}
```

View:

```
   <form method="post" action="/Student/Dispatch/"> 
    <label for="id">Student Number: </label>
     <input type="text" name="id" value="" /> <br /><br /> 
<% bool hideButton= false;
bool.TryParse(ViewData["isHideButton"],hideButton)%>
<%if(!hideButton)
{%>

    <input type="submit" value="Get Student(xls)" name="xls" /> 
<%}%>
    &nbsp;&nbsp <input type="submit" value="Get Student(pdf)" name="pdf" /> 
</form>
```