# Disable/Enable Submit Button When Returning File as Response

Tags: jquery, html

My first post!  I have an MVC 4/JQuery site where one controller manages the creation of a PDF report based on parameters passed into it from the View.  Once created the controller returns a `FileContentResult()` which prompts the end user to open or save the file.

When the end user clicks the submit button to generate the report, I'd like to disable the submit button to keep the user from clicking it twice.  Then after the report is created and the user selectes to open or save the file, I need the submit button to be re-enabled in case the user wants to change the parameters and re-run the report.  Is this doable?  How would Jquery know the end-user selected to open or save the file via the browser dialog?

Comment: One way would be to use Ajax and call you controller method, you can set the button to disabled once the function returns to view (success/failure) set it back to enabled..hope it makes sense if not can give you an example

Comment: Thanks Sam. I'll give that a go now and post my results.

Comment: Hmmm...I have concerns about ajaxifying this because I'm using a validated view model - although there's only 3 params that I need to check - drop down value, start date and end date for the range. I'd have to add some add'l validation checking/handling for the ajax piece on the serverside that I already have builtin with the MVC/postback validation.

Comment: Sam - this also doesn't look doable with AJAX anyway, because I'm returning the file in the reponse, not creating and saving it on the server where I'd then pass a link to download it.  Search SO for "ajax FileContentResult" and you'll find a few posts.

Comment: ok another thing i found is that you can use ViewData...see if it works for you here is an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710922/hide-disable-submit-button-from-controller

Comment: Thanks for contiuned feedback Sam!  Unfortunately, your link with the ViewData implementation does not fit my scenario.  I don't need to show/hide the button on the intial page load (which the ViewData solution uses).  I need to hide it (on the client) after its clicked and then when the dialog is presented to open/save, then show the button again on the main page.  I appreciate your help.  I'll go with Athiban's solution for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, just disable the submit button for few seconds and re-enable it,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var fewSeconds = 2;
    $('#Btn').click(function () {
        var btn = $(this);
        btn.prop('disabled', true);
        setTimeout(function () {
            btn.prop('disabled', false);
        }, fewSeconds * 1000);
    });

</script>
```

Comment: thanks for quick response!  I thought about going this route, but my concern with this is two-fold: 1) the report generation time varies, so it's possible that the button could be re-enabled prior to the open/save dialog and 2) if the open/save dialog appear but loses focus, it'd possible for the user to click submit again.

Comment: From my research it may not be possible to do what I'm trying accomplish.  There might be something with opening a new window and have a JS parent/child communication occur to control the button visibility on the main page, but for now I'm implementing Athiban's solution.  Thank you!